# Is it possible to clear a different session's variable?

Tags: php, session

I have a some information stored on $_SESSION, the session is stored on the database through a custom session handler.

Is there a standard way to either 'impersonate' a session having a session id or clear specific variables from another session.

I am asking about this because I have my web application, with its session variables on its own working, this is an actual shopping cart with order information using paypal. Paypal returns a response of a payment through IPN (Notifications), which are request made from their server to my site. Those requests, of course, initiate their own sessions.

What I want to find is a way to clear the original session variable from the paypal notification request that sees a different session. Is there a way to do that?

One idea might be to manually edit the database in which the session data is stored, but I want to look for something standard, regardless of the session handlers.

Comment: The standard way to "impersonate" a session is called "session hijacking"; and is typically employed by the type of people that you would normally want to protect your site against. I'd certainly be uncomfortable about using this technique against paypal.

Answer (score 1):

> I am asking about this because I have my web application, with its session variables on its own working, this is an actual shopping cart with order information using paypal. Paypal returns a response of a payment through IPN (Notifications), which are request made from their server to my site. Those requests, of course, initiate their own sessions.
>
> What I want to find is a way to clear the original session variable from the paypal notification request that sees a different session. Is there a way to do that?

If you've found yourself needing to edit data in someone else's session, you shouldn't be storing that data in a session to begin with.

If you need to read or otherwise work with the IPNs, perhaps you should store them in the database in an actual table.  You can associate the row with the user's session ID, or preferably with their login or email address.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions work because of browser cookies. If you remove the cookie, it will create a new session. If you change your cookie to one for another session, you're now impersonating that session.

You can use Chrome's developer tools, or the Web Developer Firefox addon to get easy access to your browers' cookies.

Comment: It works with cookies by default, I am using my own session handler to store data on database. I don't want to alter/change cookies or database, I am looking for a general approach

Comment: All sessions work with cookies, regardless of where you're storing them on the server. It's the only (practical) way to identify a specific user from a request. I may not be understanding your question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create a session array and giving an id to it.

like this

```
$_SESSION['ipn'] ="";
$_SESSION['ipn']= "Mescalito";
```

Comment: Not sure I follow you here, that only adds data to the $_SESSION, it's not really what I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be necessary in the first place.

I'm fairly sure you can specify a unique job ID in the IPN. Use that unique ID to find out which user the notification belongs to, and edit their data. Don't fiddle with sessions for this, it's bad design.