# php - Is this possible to unset one variable from other session?

Tags: php, session

If I want to unset one variable in current user session then I can use command `unset($_SESSION['something'])`.

Is this possible to unset only one variable from other session in case when I know PHPSESSID value (can I do it without changing current user session)? I would like check if session of PHPSESSID still exist, if exist then `unset($_SESSION['something'])` of chosen PHPSESSID.

Comment: It's possible, but it's not exactly straight forward or easy. I'd suggest that this is bad design, one user shouldn't need to do anything in another user's session. Try to look for a different way to solve whatever you want to solve.

Comment: How do you have more than one session?

Comment: I have other solution. I can enable CRON to take over the session and change one variable. `session_id($variable_PHPSESSID);
session_start();` But I would like do that in other way. I thought it can be done in more easiest way. But also I will think about reorganize my script.

Comment: The issue is that have more than one session seems a bad practice. It should be better use the effort in re-implement the whole thing, IMHO.-

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to clear a different session's variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836780/is-it-possible-to-clear-a-different-sessions-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible to unset only one variable from other session in case when I know PHPSESSID value

Yes this is possible and you need to know the session id of that session you would like to unset the variable/value from.

> can I do it without changing current user session?

If you want to do it with standard PHP functions, it's not possible without switching the session. With third-party libraries you can do that w/o switching the session.

> I would like check if session of PHPSESSID still exist, if exist then `unset($_SESSION['something'])` of chosen PHPSESSID.

This is pretty similar to an answer to [*php destroy a session which is not the current session*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8334921/367456), but only deleting a specific member:

```
$unsetFromSessionID = ... ; # set your session id from where you want to unset from
$unsetVariableName = 'something'; # set the variable name

$backupSessionID = session_id($unsetFromSessionID);
session_start(); # load session data
unset($_SESSION[$unsetVariableName]);
session_commit(); # save changes to disc

session_id($backupSessionID); # switch to current session
session_start();
```

If you want to find out if that other session was active or not, this is not possible with this method and from within PHP because PHP will create a new, empty session on `session_start()` in case it did not exists.

The alternative is to work with the session store directly, e.g. by looking for the session file on disc, loading it's contents, removing a variable and saving it back. A PHP library that is able to do that is [Serialized](https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized), it ships with an example of a [Session File Viewer](https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized/blob/master/examples/03-session/example-viewer.php) which might be a good starting point.

See also: [How to tell if a session is active?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3788369/367456)

Answer (score 0):

For better security I know that doing this is not good thing - thanks for comments under the question. So better do that by CRON task, without any user access, right?

```
session_id($variable_PHPSESSID);
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['something']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the session id on each log in, make sure to use session_regenerate_id(true) during the log in process.

```
   session_start(); 
   session_regenerate_id(true);
```